# what happened to the monthly game / competition?

Tags: discussion, community

I remember there was a prize for the best ethics question, but I can't find anything like that now? Is it not running anymore?

Answer (score 1):

We would just need some volunteers to help organize them again. It also turned out to be somewhat time-intensive composing the prompts on a weekly basis; it may be that a slower pace might be more sustainable (e.g., "epistemology month".)

Comment: i r r liked the ethics game, totally timewaster haha :D !